# How do i add an image to the python GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

The below code is a section of my code which is supposed to be a stock management system. I have encountered several problems which i would appreciate any help for.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import random
import datetime


import time;
import csv
opencsv=open('RED.csv','a')
Data=[]

LH=Label(LowerHeading, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Update", bd = 10, width = 15, anchor = 'w')
LH.grid(row=1,column=0)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
start.mainloop()
```

I Would like to add an image so for example if IDO1 is clicked by the user an image of a dress would be shown

The link didn't address my problem. I gained an error that said NO module named PIL

Comment: Let me know if you need my full code

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) Class.

Inserting images is simple.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = 'C:/xxxx/xxxx.jpg'

root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Do have a look at ***Using Images in Labels*** section of [Tkinter Labels](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php) page.

You can read Tkinter's [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) and [Label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) widgets for customizations.

**UPDATE -** 
**For installing 'PIL' from pillow -**

PIL is from package pillow. use -

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

Then `from PIL import ImageTk` will not give errors.

If `pip` is not installed then install it by using-

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: Where do i specify the file name?

Comment: my file name is dress.jpg

Comment: instead of path put *dress.jpg*

Comment: do i need to install pillow?

Comment: Yes, *Image* class is present in PIL.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: `python -m pip install pillow`

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @user9434717 You don't _have_ to install PIL it depends on the image format. If've you've read the answers in the dupe link, you'd know.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. thanks. @Nae Kindly edit the answer to add your thoughts.

Comment: I get this error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science\Inventory (new).py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: Install *Pillow* first. Else try *import Image* instead of PIL

Comment: How do i import image instead? whats the code i need to add? I'm really confused

Comment: Please see edited answer for installing `pillow`. it worked for me. I was able to load a *jpg* image. :)

Comment: the path bit doesn't work for me

Comment: i installed pillow but the rest doesn't work. i get this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ermira1\Documents\Ermira\1. Sixth Form\Year 13\Computer Science\Inventory (new).py", line 164, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="path")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3416, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3372, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "path": no such file or directory
>>>

Comment: @pro_cheats please help

Comment: remove double quotes from `"path"`. *path* is a variable containing the path to your image.